# Can ofbiz be used or developed for ITIL/ITS

Tags: ofbiz

Has anybody created a ITIL / ITSM platform using Ofbiz. Is it possible. Any thoughts. I have worked with ofbiz in past and I totally loved it's Entity and Service engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it is better to ask such questions in the user ml of the Apache OFBiz project, see here: https://ofbiz.apache.org/mailing-lists.html

in the special purpose application assetmaint a first start has been made to deliver a IS Mgt solution.